# Laravel: nested "with()" function

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to retrieve data from three tables: courses, competencies and competency_standards. The following query almost works, but it does not bring back the associated `competency_standards` table data.

```
    $coursesAndComps = Course::with(
        array('competencies' => function($query)
        {
            Competency::with('competency_standards');
        })
    )->get()->toArray();
```

Where the `competencies` table is linked to the `courses` table (competencies.course_id = course.id) and the `competency_standards` table links to the `competencies` table (competency_standards.competencey_id = competency.id).

The array returned looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => the first course
        [competencies] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9
                [course_id] => 1
                [name] => first course comp 1 
            )

            [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [course_id] => 1
                [name] => first course comp 2
            )

        )
    )

)
```

but within the `competencies` array, I was hoping to find another array called `competency_standards` like this:

...

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [course_id] => 1
        [name] => first course comp 1 
        [competency_standards] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22
                    [competency_id] => 9
                    [name] => standard foo 
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 23
                    [competency_id] => 9
                    [name] => standard bar 
                )
            )
    )
```

...

Is this possible? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It should be possible to use:

```
 $coursesAndComps = Course::with('competencies', 'competencies.standards')
                   ->get()->toArray();
```

but of course you need to have defined `standards` relationship in `Competency` model to link `Competency` with `Standard`

Comment: You don't even need to specify `competencies` first, just `with('competencies.standards')` is enough.